# How to DELETE in sql

Tags: php, sql-server

I am having trouble using the sql DELETE function

```
<?php
$sql = "DELETE FROM stasjon WHERE navn='stortinget'";
$resultat = $kobling->query ($sql);
if($kobling->query($sql)) {
    echo "Spoerringen $sql ble gjennomfoert";
} else {
    echo "Noe gikk galt med spoerringen $sql ($kobling->error).";
    ?>
```

This is the code that gives me an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file" I am quite new, som please don't use too complicated terms. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error exists because you did not close the else tag:

```
if($kobling->query($sql)) {
    echo "Spoerringen $sql ble gjennomfoert";
} else {
    echo "Noe gikk galt med spoerringen $sql ($kobling->error).";
}
```